# Google maps api 3 infobubble image clip in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, infobubble

I have this problem only in Google Chrome.

I´m using infobubble on a google maps v3, calling it with :

```
google.maps.event.addListener(markers[$mapa_marker_id], 'click', function() {infoWindow$mapa_marker_id;infoWindow$mapa_marker_id.open(map, markers[$mapa_marker_id]);});

var infoWindow<?php echo $mapa_id ?> = new InfoBubble({
content: '<div style="overflow: hidden;"><strong><?php echo $mapa_desc?></strong><br><img style="border-radius:6px;overflow: hidden " src="backoffice/thumb.php?src=associados//<?php echo $mapa_foto?>&h=170 " /><br>Site: <a href="<?php echo $mapa_site?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $mapa_site?></a></div>',
borderRadius: 6,
disableAutoPan: true,
});
```

Everything ok in all browsers except (go figure) Google Chrome

You can see the screen shot below.

[image: Example of what is going on]

Comment: you can embed images on the post which is preferred over linking to other sites.

Comment: Ok, will do that in the future, thanks for the editing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to specify the image size if it's fixed.

```
content: '<div style="overflow: hidden;">...<img style="border-radius:6px;overflow: hidden;
width:300px;height:200px" src="backoffice/thumb.php?src=associados...
```

Comment: Yep that solves the problem if image size is fixed, what about if the image size isn't fixed? This is weird only happens in google chrome. Isn't this the kind of thing our old friend internet explorer does not chrome? :)